# Hibernate - return an object based on two entities using primary and foreign keys

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, persistence

In my mysql database, I have two tables "User" and "Email". 
The column "email_id" is a **foreign key** in the table "User".

I want to use hibernate JPA to return an **Object**, containing all the details of the user with its email address, based on the **id** provided in the **User** table.

Below is a screenshot of my tables structures.

Table **User**:

[image: Table User]

Table **Email**:

[image]

Here are my java entity classes :

**Class User**

```
package com.concretepage.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private int user_id;
    @Column(name = "email_id")
    private int email_id;
    @Column(name = "user_name")
    private String user_name;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(int user_id, int email_id, String user_name) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
        this.email_id = email_id;
        this.user_name = user_name;
    }

    public int getUser_id() {
        return user_id;
    }

    public void setUser_id(int user_id) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }

    public int getEmail_id() {
        return email_id;
    }

    public void setEmail_id(int email_id) {
        this.email_id = email_id;
    }

    public String getUser_name() {
        return user_name;
    }

    public void setUser_name(String user_name) {
        this.user_name = user_name;
    }
}
```

Class **Email**

```
package com.concretepage.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "email")
public class Email implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "email_id")
    private int email_id;
    @Column(name = "email_address")
    private String email_address;

    public Email() {
    }

    public Email(int email_id, String email_address) {
        this.email_id = email_id;
        this.email_address = email_address;
    }

    public int getEmail_id() {
        return email_id;
    }

    public void setEmail_id(int email_id) {
        this.email_id = email_id;
    }

    public String getEmail_address() {
        return email_address;
    }

    public void setEmail_address(String email_address) {
        this.email_address = email_address;
    }  
}
```

Interface **User** to define the methods

```
package com.concretepage.dao;
import java.util.List;
import com.concretepage.entity.*;

public interface IUserDAO {
    List<User> getAllUser();
    User getUserBy(int userId);
}
```

Interface **Email** to define the methods

```
package com.concretepage.dao;
import java.util.List;
import com.concretepage.entity.*;

public interface IEmailDAO {
    List<Email> getAllEmails();
    Email getEmailById(int emailId);
}
```

**Implementation** of the interface **User**

```
package com.concretepage.dao;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.concretepage.entity.*;
@Transactional
@Repository
public class UserDAO implements IUserDAO {

    @PersistenceContext 
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public List<User> getAllUser() {
        String hql = "FROM User as user ORDER BY user.user_id";
        return (List<User>) entityManager.createQuery(hql).getResultList();
    }

    @Override
    public User getUserBy(int userId) {
        return entityManager.find(User.class, userId);
    }   
}
```

**Implementation** of the interface **Email**

```
package com.concretepage.dao;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.concretepage.entity.*;

@Transactional
@Repository
public class EmailDAO implements IEmailDAO {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public List<Email> getAllEmails() {
        String hql = "FROM Email as email ORDER by email.email_id";
        return (List<Email>) entityManager.createQuery(hql).getResultList();
    }

    @Override
    public Email getEmailById(int emailId) {
        return entityManager.find(Email.class, emailId);
    }

}
```

Controller class to call the services

```
package com.concretepage.controller;
import com.concretepage.dao.IUserDAO;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import com.concretepage.entity.*;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("user")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private IUserDAO userService;


    @GetMapping("users")
    public ResponseEntity<List<User>> getAllUser() {
        List<User> list = userService.getAllUser();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(list, HttpStatus.OK);
        }

       @GetMapping("users/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<User> getUserBy(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
        User user = userService.getUserBy(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

I need to the email address of the user with Id = 1 together with his name.

Below is a screenshot of the object expected :
[image]

Comment: If something is a foreign key then you need a RELATION (e.g `@OneToOne`) on the field that it represents. Any JPA docs would tell you how.

Comment: Where do i put the @OneToOne Relation ? Could you please provide an example. Checked in the JPA docs but could not implement it.

Comment: "checked in the JPA docs" ... right. Ones like these? http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_1/jpa/mapping.html#one_one_relations  because it is simple enough how to do it

Comment: The docs do not show how to implement the method

Comment: care to share with the world what is "the method"? The page linked tells you how to implement a 1-1 relation in JPA, which you haven't done in your post.

Answer (score 1):

Check this, https://gigsterous.github.io/engineering/2016/09/25/spring-boot-2.html use the annotations to create relationships between entities.